# Were there any ancient prophets B.C. considered of the same God?

Tags: life-of-jesus

**EDIT** - **New question.**

Christianity has only been around for a very small percentage of time, when we look at all the prophets and world religions that came before Christianity.

- Were there any [ancient prophets](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090107220826AAPLoRw) considered of the same God
  described in Christianity (besides Moses)? OF the far east, near east, south America or Europe.

My pastor told us a story that when Evangelicals went to convert believers in far east lands, they would tell people that Jesus was the son of their God - as a way to gain them in Christ.

So does this mean that every prophet before Christ was of the same God, some of them or there was no salvation?

Thank You.

Comment: Most of this question seems to be covered by the previous one that people have voted as a duplicate. However there might be a couple aspects that are unique: particularly about the prophets. However it is also entirely unclear what that question is. If that aspect is important, I'd encourage to you ask a much more focused question about that specific issue.

Comment: You may be interested in Don Richardson's books "Peace Child", "Eternity in their Hearts", and "Lords of the Earth". He expounds on redemptive analogies, or cultural elements implanted by God in foreign cultures that correlate with Christian ideas, enabling dialogue and facilitating missionary work.

Answer (score -3):

Salvation for the Jews (before Christ) was to observe Torah.

Salvation for the Gentiles (everybody before even the Torah was given) was to follow their conscience.

> **Romans 2:15-16 NET** They show that the work of the law is written in their hearts, as their conscience bears witness and their
>   conflicting thoughts accuse or else defend them, on the day when God
>   will judge the secrets of human hearts, according to my gospel through
>   Christ Jesus.

Paul tells us that those who followed the law, whether Torah or conscience, all died:

> **Romans 7:10 NET**  and I died. So I found that the very commandment that was intended to
>   bring life brought death!

However, they did not go to hell. Paul says they were held in protective custody. The law acted as their guardian, pedagogos, until Christ came:

> **Galatians 3:24 NET**  Thus the law had become our guardian until Christ, so that we could be
>   declared righteous by faith.

IOW, the law could distinguish, and separate, and preserve, those who believed God existed and tried to follow Him, but it could not give life. They were not dead, like the people described here, who had no opportunity to come to God because of their refusal to follow the law:

> **Luke 9:60 NET** But Jesus said to him, “Let the dead bury their own dead, but as for
>   you, go and proclaim the kingdom of God.”

They were kept safe, but could not taste eternaL life. Eternal life is not just immortality, but also living in synch with God, a mode of living, what Judaism calls chayei olam, the life of the world to come:

http://www.hebrew4christians.com/Articles/Chayei-Olam/chayei-olam.html

Those who believe Jesus's message have passed into eternal life, entered the Kingdom:

> **John 5:24-27 NET** “I tell you the solemn truth, the one who hears my message and
>   believes the one who sent me has eternal life and will not be
>   condemned, but has crossed over from death to life. I tell you the
>   solemn truth, a time is coming – and is now here – when the dead will
>   hear the voice of the Son of God, and those who hear will live. For
>   just as the Father has life in himself, thus he has granted the Son to
>   have life in himself, and he has granted the Son authority to execute
>   judgment, because he is the Son of Man.
>
> **John 5:19-21 NET** So Jesus answered them, “I tell you the solemn truth, the Son can do
>   nothing on his own initiative, but only what he sees the Father doing.
>   For whatever the Father does, the Son does likewise. For the Father
>   loves the Son and shows him everything he does, and will show him
>   greater deeds than these, so that you will be amazed. For just as the
>   Father raises the dead and gives them life, so also the Son gives life
>   to whomever he wishes.